# How to access a sibling Vuex state property and getters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have data to populate and update in different scenarios.
In these scenarios, i need to populate the "href" and "href2"
Anytime i try populating as written in the code below, i get

1. **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined - (trying to reference from getters)**
2. Likewise when referencing from sibling Vuex state data **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'locationId' of undefined**

This is a sample snippet from my Vuex Store.

**Note:** This reference/call i am trying to do is within my Vuex Store.

I need help knowing how to properly reference these datas within the Vuex Store.
Thank you in advance.

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    defaultLocationId: "/...",
    updatedLocationFromAction: "",
    navData: [
      ...,
      {
        title: "Location",
        icon: "fa fa-map-marker",
        href: "/locations/" + this.defaultLocationId,
        href2: "/locations/" + this.getters.anotherLocation,
      },
      ...,
    ],
  },
  getters: {
    anotherLocation(state) {
      return state.updatedLocationFromAction;
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Vuex getters/mutations/actions are `pure` functions - there is no `this` like in Vue components and all the information is passed through arguments only. You should remove `href` and `href2` from the state and convert them to getter functions.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change state, you need to use mutation and for retrieving use getters. Here is a nice working example of vuex in codepen. Check it out:

https://codepen.io/brokyo/pen/rGRZxe

```
mutations: {
    UPDATE_DATA (state, payload) { // your location change
      state.person = payload
    }
  }
```